# How to launch Call+Sms filter which is a preinstalled application on Lumia devices?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Anyone knows Call+Sms filter app's Uri association scheme? I want to launch it from my own app. I see someone have did it at [this app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/store/app/%E9%AA%9A%E6%89%B0%E6%8B%A6%E6%88%AA%E5%8A%A9%E6%89%8B/29b493d4-c86a-4638-af4d-c9b108a95d8f) on Windows Phone Store.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not documented for the public.
Perhaps it's only open for OEM developers.